# Numbering equations with figures

Tags: floats, equations, numbering

I need to asign a number to equation which contains figure. My code is

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage[slovak]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{palatino,verbatim}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item Self-energy:
\[
\raisebox{-3mm}{\includegraphics[width=0.8cm]{SelfEnergyAll.pdf}}
\qquad
\begin{aligned}
= -i\Sigma(p,\mathring{m},\mathring{g})(2\pi)^4 \delta(p_f - p_i) 
\end{aligned}
\]

\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Is there any way how to do that? By the way, is there a better way how to write this type of equations (I need to use them very often). Thanks.

Comment: Why not just use `\begin{equation}` and `\end{equation}` in place of `\[` and `\]`? Then the equation will be numbered.

Comment: Well, good point, thank you. I didn´t think that would work. Anyway, is it possible to place the figure in front of the equation in any smarter way? Because now, if the equation becomes longer, I need to raise the figure more. I would like to have the figure always at the same position in front of the first `=`.

Answer (score 6):

You can just use an `equation` environment instead of `\[...\]`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article} 

\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item Self-energy:
  \begin{equation}
    \vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[width=0.8cm]{example-image-a}}}
    = -i\Sigma(p,\mathring{m},\mathring{g})(2\pi)^4 \delta(p_f - p_i) 
  \end{equation}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

`\vcenter` will center the box vertically with respect to the x-axis of the equation.

Comment: With `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}` you can do `\includegraphics[width=0.8cm,valign=c]{file}`

Comment: @egreg That's a nice alternative

Answer (score 0):

Andrew's answer probably is what you are looking for. If you want to share numbering with figures I think you should use the figure environment:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[slovak]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{palatino,verbatim}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{todonotes}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\caption{}
\label{a fig}
\begin{itemize}
\item Self-energy:

%\raisebox{-3mm}[0cm][0cm]{\missingfigure[figwidth=0.8cm]{testing}}
\missingfigure[figwidth=0.8cm]{testing}
\[
\qquad
\begin{aligned}
= -i\Sigma(p,\mathring{m},\mathring{g})(2\pi)^4 \delta(p_f - p_i)
\end{aligned}
\]

\end{itemize}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that `figure`s float...